# Am I able to show my Taskbar on some of my displays?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, taskbar

I have two monitors plugged into my laptop, am I able to have a Taskbar on both of the monitors but not at all on the laptop screen?

The laptop screen is not my 'main screen'.

Thank you!

Comment: The main screen will have the taskbar, no matter which monitor that is set to in Windows display settings. How to get a taskbar on the second monitor, that I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can set to show the Taskbar only on one primary screen or on all display screens.

We can refer [How to Hide or Show Taskbar on Multiple Displays in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3899-hide-show-taskbar-multiple-displays-windows-10-a.html)

For showing Taskbar on some of our display screens, we are unable to find the relevant settings in Windows display settings. But I search a Dual Monitor Taskbar tool, we can try to see if the tool can achieve our needs:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately the provided software doesn't solve my problem as far as I can see.